# When entering Canada, can Canadian citizens declare another nationality without mentioning their Canadian citizenship?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada

On the plane, someone in the family near me couldn't find their Canadian passport. She left it in Vietnam, and forgot to bring it on the plane. She said they have dual citizenship  of Vietnam. Family suggested she enters Canada customs with just their Vietnam passport. But don't say anything about Canadian passport or forgetting it!

My first question, are Canadians mandated to disclose their nationality when entering Canada?

Second, what happens if Canada customs officer finds out this Vietnamese didn't disclose? What's maximum fine, penalty?

Comment: Related, not quite duplicate:  https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/61237/4171

Comment: Vietnamese nationals require a visa to enter Canada. It's highly unlikely that a citizen of Canada would apply for or be granted a visa for Canada (in fact, replace Canada in this sentence with any other country). It's also unlikely the passenger would have been allowed to board without valid entry documents for Canada. This is a bizarre scenario.

Answer (score 1):

[Officially](https://www.cic.gc.ca/ENGLISH/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=1100&top=16), the government wants you to use your Canadian passport:

> Canadian citizens, including dual citizens, cannot apply for an eTA to enter Canada. You will need a valid Canadian passport to board your flight to Canada.

And on [another page](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/dual-canadian-citizens-visit-canada.html):

> Dual Canadian citizens can no longer travel to or transit through Canada by air with a non-Canadian passport. You need a valid Canadian passport to board your flight.

(That page also includes what to do if you don't have your Canadian passport and don't have time to get one before you travel.)

That said, I know a person whose Canadian passport had expired and who had a valid British passport. She applied for and got an ETA and entered as a British person without mentioning that she also was a Canadian citizen. I don't know what would have happened if immigration had become aware of her dual citizenship, and wouldn't recommend this action to anyone else.

Since everyone needs either a visitor visa or an ETA, I don't know how your plane mate got on the plane without their Canadian passport, and I don't know how they expected to be admitted.

Comment: Americans don't need an ETA, so [dual Canada-US citizens can still fly to Canada with a US passport](https://travel.gc.ca/travelling/documents/dual-citizenship). I don't think Canada has a law requiring Canadians to enter with a Canadian passport, but telling lies on an ETA application might be an issue.